# Can I prevent macOS from asking for keyboard type every time?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I use a lot of keyboards and I flash their firmware often. Every time macOS recognizes a new keyboard, it'd ask me to press the keys next to the shifts to identify the layout. It can be annoying if you get asked more than a handful times a day. The thing is, I always use ANSI keyboards. Is there a way to shut it up? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

## No.

There is no method to do this. Apparently in the eyes of Apple where nothing is configurable and everything is assumed, it's better to NOT assume that a user in Texas that has only ever used QWERTY keyboards is plugging in a QWERTY keyboard then to ask him about this..

Not just is this configurable which is shocking, but it has no default.

## Workaround

Install Linux.

Comment: Not sure this qualifies as a helpful answer, it rather seems like a rant.

Comment: @nohillside maybe not my best, but still well warranted. You shouldn't have to configure a "plug and play" usb keyboard. This was handled better in Windows 95. Took them 30 years of a better design to figure, "we should require configuration on this every time".